# How to hide error information when entire app crashes in React js

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on ReactJS and I want to hide all the information about a crash if the app crashes. I mean, is there a way of redirect to a page when something crashes, or at least render something different from this?

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code sample, your ultils maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) component, this will catch all children errors from your app

You then could wrap around your App like so:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <App />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010) is a live demo made by React core team.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It resolved my problem. Greetings!